# material UI Modal won't close

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));


const classes = useStyles();

<Modal
  className={classes.modal}
  open={eval(`${page}_modal`)}
  onClose={() => eval(`set_${page}_modal`)(false)}
  aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
  aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
  closeAfterTransition
  BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
  BackdropProps={{
    timeout: 500,
  }}
>
  <Child />
</Modal>
```

The above contains all of my code regarding my modal.

When a button is clicked, it opens up the `<Child />` in the middle of the screen like it should. But clicking outside of the modal does not close it. pressing escape does not close it. It does not have an (X) close button. So bottom line is, it can't be closed.

Furthermore, it appears to cause my page to re-render.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using react's `useState`   for `open`?

Comment: It is useState. The problem is, page is a variable. So I need to turn a string into a useState